# How to enable Desktop Settings > Wallpaper > Layout in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu

After upgrading from Kubuntu 14.04 to 16.04, I'm unable to get my desktop folder to display on the desktop. I believe the correct way to do this is:

1. Right click on the desktop
2. Desktop Settings
3. Wallpaper
4. Layout: Folder View

However, the Layout option is set to "Desktop", and the "Desktop" option is disabled, so I can't change it.

How can I reenable the Folder View option?

Comment: Sadly and cryptically, appears to have fixed itself. Maybe just an update. Around the time it was fixed, I did add a Folder View widget to my desktop as a workaround. Checking back in the Wallpaper > Layout, Folder View was now an option. I removed the widget and everything was as I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to enable the option "folder view", before doing those steps you must set up the option "unlock widgets". To do that click with the right button in a widget, for instance where you have the date, and chose "unlock widgets".

After that, the steps you have mentioned shall work.

Comment: I think I understand why this is the case, but egad, what a mess from a user's point of view.